# Jenkins C# Couldn't find any revision to build

Tags: c#, jenkins, build

Всем привет.
Не могу собрать проект.
Данные из лог файла сборки.

> Started by user Pit Piter
> Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CalculateInConsole
> git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
> Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git.exe config remote.origin.url https://gitlab.com/PitPiter/calculateinconsole.git # timeout=10
> Fetching upstream changes from https://gitlab.com/PitPiter/calculateinconsole.git
> git.exe --version # timeout=10
> using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials
> git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://gitlab.com/PitPiter/calculateinconsole.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
> git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
> git.exe rev-parse "origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
>
> ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
>
> Finished: FAILURE

И на картинках сборки и шаги сборки.
[image: Конфигурация глобальных инструментов]
[image: Настройки проекта]

Управление исходным кодом:
[image: Настройки управления исходным кодом]

Не совсем уверен, что проблема именно в Jenkins. Так как судя по:

> git.exe rev-parse "origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
>
> ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.

-то вполне может быть проблема и в настройках доступа к ветке мастер в gitlab, но я даже не знаю как проверить строку:

> git.exe rev-parse "origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10

Так как через тот же git в VS 2017 и залился проект на Gitlab.

Comment: как насчет `Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.`?

Comment: tym32167, подключение к репозиторию пишет успех и через сборочную директорию могу закачать полностью весь проект с gitlab. А про ветвь настроек, я так понимаю, это и есть настройки проекта в jenkins, то там как раз задается шаг сборки, т.е. чем собирается, куда собирается. Это как раз второй рисунок.